# Can I get two diamonds?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election, moderator-abilities, nominations

For some reason, the election page does not seem to be detecting existing moderators correctly. Most notably the form to nominate yourself is not disabled like, I believe, it used to be. I was able to enter a nomination for myself in the [CSE election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/2) in spite of already [being a moderator there](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators):

[image: double mod]

If, on the other hand, I could earn double-diamond status please let me know in the next few hours so I can write up a real nomination before the voting starts!

Comment: Nomination when you already have a diamond is necessary in the first election, as the pro-tem moderators have to run to stay mods. I don't think this case merits having those rules hard-coded into the election software, it is not really a problem in practice.

Comment: I always assumed it was just a "You're a moderator, you should know not to do that" thing.

Comment: Huh. I distinctly noticed when this election started that I was NOT shown the link to nominate and remember thinking to myself how not-fun that was. Then yesterday I noticed it was there, and today curiosity got the better of me. Perhaps it was my imagination that got the best of me a few days ago in not seeing it?

Comment: No, but the diamond you already have will get bigger and shinier.

Comment: You can double diamond yourself by just appending the Unicode diamond to your username. Non-moderators, this makes you a moderator instantly!

Comment: @ColeJohnson Last I checked they were actually filtering that out as a result of some abuse. It's one of the few hard coded restrictions on display names. And I would know this because...nevermind.

Comment: @Shadow sadly that Q has an upvote from the 2011 me so I cannot even plead ignorance.

Comment: No worry @Caleb, happens to the best! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently SE assumes moderators are more that just monkeys with guns and we'll actually know what to do with the tools we are given—including when *not* to use them.

[image: moderators]

I'm sorry for to have proven that assumption wrong and the public stereo type correct.

P.S. Hat tip to Mad Scientist's note of:

> Nomination when you already have a diamond is necessary in the first election, as the pro-tem moderators have to run to stay mods.